# Investigating the java exception

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have controller and service class (Spring and Hibernate 4). The controller class contains the `getTransactionsForInternalUse` method as shown below :

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/internal/financials/transactions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
          @ResponseBody
          public ResponseEntity<SetRESTData<FinancialTransactionDTO>> getTransactionsForInternalUse(

            @RequestParam(value = "businessId", required = true) final String businessId,
            @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) final String statusString,
            @RequestParam(value = "transactionMethod", required = false) final String transactionMethodString,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false) final String orderBy,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortDirection", required = false) final String sortDirectionString) {

            final FinancialTransactionStatus status = StringUtils.isBlank(statusString) ? null : FinancialTransactionStatus.fromCode(statusString);
            final FinancialTransactionMethod method =
              StringUtils.isBlank(transactionMethodString) ? null : FinancialTransactionMethod.fromCode(transactionMethodString);

            final FinancialTransactionPaginationData paginationData = StringUtils.isBlank(orderBy) ?
              null : new FinancialTransactionPaginationData(FinancialTransactionSortableField.fromCode(orderBy), null, null, sortDirectionString);

 //call to getTransactionsForEmployeeUse method 


            final ServiceResultDetails<Set<FinancialTransactionDTO>> resultsDetails =
   financialTransactionService.getTransactionsForEmployeeUse(businessId,status, method, paginationData);// Added business Id here
            final ResponseCode errorCode = resultsDetails.getErrorCode();
            if (errorCode != null) {
              return buildNoCacheNoCorsEmptySetRESTDataWithMessage(errorCode, resultsDetails.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
              return buildNoCacheSetRESTDataResponse(
                resultsDetails.getEntity(), ResponseCode.FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_RETRIEVED, ResponseCode.FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_NOT_FOUND, false);
            }
          }
```

And, `getTransactionsForEmployeeUse` method of `FinancialTransactionService` class is called using it's object `financialTransactionService` as shown above. The method
of `getTransactionsForEmployeeUse` defined in `FinancialTransactionService` is as follows :

```
     @Transactional(value = TransactionManagerName.BUSINESS, readOnly = true)
      @TransactionalSecurity(employeeAccess = true)
      public ServiceResultDetails<Set<FinancialTransactionDTO>> getTransactionsForEmployeeUse(
              @NotBlank final String businessExternalId,
              final FinancialTransactionStatus status,
              final FinancialTransactionMethod method,
              final FinancialTransactionPaginationData paginationData) {
          final Business escrowProvider = businessService.getByExternalId(businessExternalId);
          final BusinessId escrowProviderId = escrowProvider.getId();
          final BusinessPartnership businessPartnership = businessPartnershipService.getPartnership(escrowProviderId);

//The below line is line #223 from the stacktrace and in the code
          if (!Boolean.TRUE.equals(businessPartnership.getEscrowProvider())) {
              return new ServiceResultDetails<>(ResponseCode.OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED_FOR_NON_ESCROW_PROVIDERS);
          }
          final Set<FinancialAccount> accounts = financialAccountService.getAccountsAtHoldingPartner(escrowProviderId);
          final Map<FinancialAccountId, FinancialAccount> accountIdMap = entityHelper.buildIdEntityMap(accounts);
          final Set<FinancialTransaction> financialTransactions =
                  financialTransactionDAO.getAllTransactionsForEmployeeUse(status, method, paginationData);
          final Set<FinancialTransactionDTO> resultsAll = new LinkedHashSet<>(financialTransactions.size()); 
          for (final FinancialTransaction financialTransaction : financialTransactions) {
              if(financialTransaction instanceof InvestmentTransaction){
                  final FinancialAccountId fromEscrowAccountId = ((InvestmentTransaction) financialTransaction).getFromEscrowAccountId();
                  final FinancialAccount fromEscrowAccount = fromEscrowAccountId == null ? null : accountIdMap.get(fromEscrowAccountId);
                  if(fromEscrowAccount != null){
                      resultsAll.add(new FinancialTransactionDTO(financialTransaction,fromEscrowAccount));
                  }else{
                      resultsAll.add(new FinancialTransactionDTO(financialTransaction));
                  }
              }else {
                  resultsAll.add(new FinancialTransactionDTO(financialTransaction));
              }
          }
          return new ServiceResultDetails<>(resultsAll);    
      }
```

I have been getting this error for the past few days when I run an API Call (GET) using a REST client and before few days I wasn't getting this error.I haven't done any code changes and wondering what could be the problem. 
I tried debugging using Remote Java Application but couldn't see why NPE is thrown.The stacktrace is below:

```
1723:44.616 080-exec-3 LId:2001   PId:2001   r.SessionManagementInterceptor ERROR Uncaught exception from FinancialTransactionsController, getTransactionsForInternalUse
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fp.investing.service.transaction.FinancialTransactionService.getTransactionsForEmployeeUse(FinancialTransactionService.java:223) ~[investing-api-1.0.13579.jar:13579]
    at com.fp.investing.service.transaction.FinancialTransactionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dea301d.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:13579]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.fp.investing.service.transaction.FinancialTransactionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a21fc6da.getTransactionsForEmployeeUse(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:13579]
    at com.fp.investing.service.transaction.FinancialTransactionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dea301d.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:13579]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.fp.core.tx.TransactionalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(TransactionalSecurityInterceptor.java:96) ~[core-api-1.0.13579.jar:13579]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.fp.investing.service.transaction.FinancialTransactionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a68dac2.getTransactionsForEmployeeUse(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:13579]
    at com.fp.core.ws.financial.FinancialTransactionsController.getTransactionsForInternalUse(FinancialTransactionsController.java:78) ~[core-ws-1.0.13579.jar:13579]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.fp.core.ws.http.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:39) [core-ws-1.0.13579.jar:13579]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
```

Comment: Please at least mark (f.e. using a comment) where is line 223 in FinancialTransactionService (from stack trace)...

Comment: @Betlista Done. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `businessPartnership` is null.

Comment: @dimo414 You are right, setting breakpoint on line #223 gave me businessPartnership as null. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look at line 223:

> ```
> if (!Boolean.TRUE.equals(businessPartnership.getEscrowProvider())) {
> ```

We know `Boolean.TRUE` cannot be `null`, since it's [`true`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#TRUE). We also know that [`Boolean.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) will return `false` if passed `null`, not raise a `NullPointerException`, so it wouldn't matter if `businessPartnership.getEscrowProvider()` returned `null`. The only remaining cause is `businessPartnership`.  You cannot call methods on `null`, if you attempt to do so you will cause a `NullPointerException`. From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.6):

> A method invocation expression (§15.12) that invokes an instance method throws a `NullPointerException` if the target reference is `null`.

The canonical [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/113632) covers this in greater detail, but in essence you are missing some necessary sanity checks before this line. At line 223 you assume `businessPartnership` cannot be `null`, yet `businessPartnershipService.getPartnership()` returns `null` in some cases. Either ensure `businessPartnershipService.getPartnership()` never returns `null`, or add null-checks before calling `businessPartnership.getEscrowProvider()`.

Comment: Thanks. I have commented that portion of code and trying to test now.

Comment: After testing, I didn't get the exception. Thanks again for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you understand why you got the exception in the first place? You cannot call methods on `null`.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Thanks @dimo414